# Decide the start of the circular gas station path

Tags: java, queue

> Suppose there is a circle. There are n petrol pumps on that circle. You are given two sets of data.
>
> 1. The amount of petrol that petrol pump will give.
> 2. Distance from that petrol pump to the next petrol pump.
>
> Calculate the first point from where a truck will be able to complete the circle (The truck will stop at each petrol pump and it has infinite capacity). Expected time complexity is O(n). Assume for 1 litre petrol, the truck can go 1 unit of distance.
>
> For example, let there be 4 petrol pumps with amount of petrol and distance to next petrol pump value pairs as {4, 6}, {6, 5}, {7, 3} and {4, 5}. The first point from where truck can make a circular tour is 2nd petrol pump. Output should be “start = 1″ (index of 2nd petrol pump).

Looking for code-review, best-practices and optimizations.

```
public final class PetrolPumpCircularTour {
    
    private PetrolPumpCircularTour() {};

    public static int startingStations(List<PetrolPumpData> gasStations) {
        
        if (gasStations.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There should be atleast a single gas stats");
        }
        
        int front = 0;
        int rear = 0; // is actually 0, after a circle. but 1 is just a game we play for circular queue.
        
        int statationsCovered = 0;
        int gasSavedSoFar = 0;
        
        while (statationsCovered < gasStations.size()) {
            int currentPetrol = gasStations.get(rear).getLitres() + gasSavedSoFar;
            int currentDistance = gasStations.get(rear).getDistance();
            gasSavedSoFar = currentPetrol - currentDistance;
            statationsCovered = statationsCovered + 1;
            
            if (gasSavedSoFar < 0) {
                rear = (rear + 1) % gasStations.size();
                front =  (front + 1) % gasStations.size();
                gasSavedSoFar = 0;
                statationsCovered = 0;
                if (rear == 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                rear = (rear + 1) % gasStations.size();
            }
        }
            
        return front;
    }
}


public class PetrolPumpCircularTourTest {
    
    @Test
    public void test1( ) {
        List<PetrolPumpData> list1 = new ArrayList<PetrolPumpData>();
        list1.add(new PetrolPumpData(4, 6));
        list1.add(new PetrolPumpData(6, 5));
        list1.add(new PetrolPumpData(7, 3));
        list1.add(new PetrolPumpData(4, 5));
        
        assertEquals(1, PetrolPumpCircularTour.startingStations(list1));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        List<PetrolPumpData> list2 = new ArrayList<PetrolPumpData>();
        list2.add(new PetrolPumpData(40, 6));
        list2.add(new PetrolPumpData(6, 5));
        list2.add(new PetrolPumpData(7, 3));
        list2.add(new PetrolPumpData(4, 5));
        
        assertEquals(0, PetrolPumpCircularTour.startingStations(list2));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test3() {
        List<PetrolPumpData> list3 = new ArrayList<PetrolPumpData>();
        list3.add(new PetrolPumpData(4, 6));
        list3.add(new PetrolPumpData(3, 5));
        list3.add(new PetrolPumpData(70, 3));
        list3.add(new PetrolPumpData(4, 5));
        
        assertEquals(2, PetrolPumpCircularTour.startingStations(list3));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test4( ) {
        List<PetrolPumpData> list4 = new ArrayList<PetrolPumpData>();
        list4.add(new PetrolPumpData(4, 6));
        list4.add(new PetrolPumpData(3, 5));
        list4.add(new PetrolPumpData(2, 3));
        list4.add(new PetrolPumpData(40, 5));
        
        assertEquals(3, PetrolPumpCircularTour.startingStations(list4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you *prove* the algorithm works? It really looks suspicious. Besides, running it against a

```
{4,6}, {6,5}, {1,3}, {7,3}, {4,5}
```

test case returns `2`. (Hint: the correct algorithm is much simpler).

Answer (score 1):

At first look, this seems to be an exercise in using the [remainder/modulus operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html)

We have a circular list of details that we need to evaluate the list starting at different points along it.

We can evaluate a list as a circular list by using the remainder `%` operator like this

```
for(int index = 0; index < allStations.length; index++){
    int currentStation = allStations[(index + startingPoint) % allStations.length];
// do something with the current station
}
```

**Note:** I am using an array for the list rather than a `List` for ease.

The solution should be a moving window along the circular list. For each starting point (0 => allStations.length), check if this is a valid route. If it is, return the starting point.  A route is valid, if the cumulative fuel balance is not negative.